# Outgoing call receiver error

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, call

I have mistake my code. when I enter "1234", code is running but I enter another number e.g. "2525" stopped my application.

```
String phoneNumber = getResultData();
    if (phoneNumber == null) {            
        phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    }
   if(phoneNumber.equals("1234")){ // DialedNumber checking.            
        setResultData(null);
        Intent i=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        context.startActivity(i);

    } else {
        phoneNumber = getResultData();
    }
```

Comment: post code of `getResultData();`

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.vizteck.navigationdrawer.AramaDinleme: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2336)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:141)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my true code.

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL))
```

I added this code and good run. thanks for helps